# Reading Lines of Input into Array in Scala?

Tags: arrays, string, scala

I have 10 lines of input I am reading from `stdin` via `readLine()`. How can I read these 10 lines into an array of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a range from 1 to 10 with `1 to 10` and then map over it while not caring about the actual numbers, only reading lines:

```
(1 to 10).map(_ => readLine()).toArray
```

As asked in your comment, printing out arrays easily can't be done just by calling `println` on them, but `Seq`s support it:

```
scala> println(Array("a", "b", "c"))
[Ljava.lang.String;@60b85ba1

scala> println(Seq("a", "b", "c"))
List(a, b, c)
```

Comment: I had tried this already actually and when I printed it, it gave me a bunch of gibberish for some reason: `[Ljava.lang.String@bunch of numbers`

Comment: Because `Array` is just a Java array meaning the `toString` method is a default method and prints the type + hashCode. Use `.toSeq` instead to get a Scala sequence. Updated my answer with examples.

Comment: To print out an array, try: `a.mkString(", ")`

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more direct approach:

```
Array.fill(10){readLine()}
```